# SQL Server transaction replication ignores DML which does not change data

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

I have a transactional replication setup between the two servers and I noticed that if a run a statement similar to this:

UPDATE mytable
SET mycolumn = mycolumn

the replication somehow knows to ignore this transaction and it does not get applied on the subscriber. I have confirmed it by running SQL Profiler and also by adding TIMESTAMP column to my subscriber table (it does not change).  I suspect there is some sort of mechanism, which enables this kind of "smart" behavior and I was wondering if anybody could shed some light on it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tranactional Replication [works by reading the transaction log](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151706%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

This kind of "non updating update" often won't generate any transaction log records.

See Paul White's article [The Impact of Non-Updating Updates](http://web.archive.org/web/20180406220621/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/11/the_2D00_impact_2D00_of_2D00_update_2D00_statements_2D00_that_2D00_don_2D00_t_2D00_change_2D00_data.aspx) for more about this.